# A model of geometry with the negation of Pasch’s axiom?

Tags: geometry, model-theory, axioms

How would a geometry with all the usual axioms of Euclidean geometry, except that instead of [Pasch’s axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch%27s_axiom), we take it negation, look like?

Comment: What do you take as "the usual axioms of Euclidean geometry"? [Hilbert's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_axioms)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For *elementary* geometry without the Pasch Axiom, every model is isomorphic to a Cartesian plane over a formally real Pythagorean semi-ordered field $\mathcal{F}$.

More can be said if our geometry has the full second-order continuity axiom. For then $\mathcal{F}$ is (as a field) isomorphic to the reals.

Now let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-linear solution of the Cauchy functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, where $f$ is onto and $0\lt f(1)$. Define the order relation $\lt^\ast$ by $x\lt^\ast y$ if $f(x)\lt f(y)$. Then under $\lt^\ast$ and ordinary addition, the reals form an ordered group. The Cartesian plane over the reals, with order relation given by $\lt^\ast$, is a non-Paschian model of geometry with second-order continuity.

References: The use of the Cauchy functional equation to produce a non-Paschian geometry is due to Szczerba, *Independence of Pasch's Axiom* (1970).
A proof that all non-Paschian geometries with full continuity axiom are of the shape described by Szczerba was given by Adler, *Determinateness and the Pasch Axiom*, 1971.

**Remark:** The second result has an interesting consequence. Under suitable conditions, we can have a model of ZF in which all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable. In such a model, any model of the Hilbert second-order geometry minus the Pasch Axiom is automatically Paschian!

Comment: Why is $(\mathbb R,<^*)$ not isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,<)$?

Comment: I think I see already - you can have a $<^*$-positive times a $<^*$-positive be $<^*$-negative

Comment: Does this mean Pasch's axiom is equivalent to requiring that line segments be closed (in the sense of topology)?

Comment: Hm - maybe not - maybe scrambling the order scrambles the topology as well so it still thinks line segments are closed?