# Famous False Theorems in Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, math-history

Until about the 1870s, an example of a well-known false theorem in real analysis was Ampere's theorem, which has the following false statement.

Propotision.(Ampere's Theorem)
Any continuous function is differentiable except at a finite number of isolated points.

Now shown to be false by the work of Weierstrass et al, but how was this once proved?

Comment: Check this: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3480, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/787630/42969

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!