# Why is the line/plane separation postulate necessary?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, axioms

Usually when we introduce postulates it is so they are of some use to us. I do not see the reason for these two.

> The Line Separation Postulate: Each point on a given line divides the line into three disjoint sets: the set containing the point, and the two half lines on either side of the point.

> The Plane Separation Postulate: Each line within any plane divides the plane into three disjoint sets: The line and the two half-planes on either side of the line.

I understand the postulates and what they are saying, but I do not see how they can be used. And I have not yet found a proof that uses them in the book.

I guess I am not convinced of their fruitfulness so if anyone can help convince me these are useful/necessary postulates that would be of great help.

Comment: Which book? I seem to recall identifying that one in a book on non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: *Geometry*, Bob Jones University Press. It's a high school book.

Comment: See the [Missing Strip Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973496/model-of-ordered-plane-with-the-negation-of-paschs-axiom) and [Pasch's axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch%27s_axiom).

Comment: See also [Are there simple models of Euclid's postulates that violate Pasch's theorem or Pasch's axiom?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352566/are-there-simple-models-of-euclids-postulates-that-violate-paschs-theorem-or-p)

Comment: Consider the simple case of the line: if the axiom does not hold, a *circle* may be used to model the line. But a single point on a circle does not divide it in two "separate" parts.